# MongoDB - How to get all documents not being referenced by any document in a different collection

Tags: database, mongodb

We have two collections, `Teams` and `Matches`. Every time a Match is reported, a new document is saved in that collection and its added to an array in the Team documents (teams[i].matches).
A now solved bug in our system has caused that the new Matches document were not referenced in their respectives Teams documents.
Is there a query for `Mongo DB 3.6.9` that can help us find the Matches not referenced in Teams?

Comment: Please supply an example of the `Teams` and `Matches` docs with some guidance around exactly what fields in the structures require the linkages.

Answer (score 0):

An aggregation pipeline may help you, using `$lookup`.

- `$lookup` fetches documents `from "Teams"` that match the `pipeline`'s `$match`.
- `let: { match_id: "$_id" }` create a variable `match_id` corresponding to `Match`'s `_id`.
- `$match` expression keeps only `Teams`  with `match_id` into `Team`'s `matches` array.
- `as: "matches"` stores `Team` that validate previous `$match`.
- Last `$match` after `$lookup` step keeps `matches` array that are empty (`Matches` with no `Teams`)

```
db.Matches.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Teams",
            let: { match_id: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [{
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $in: [ "$$match_id", "$matches" ]
                    }
                }
            }],
            as: "matches"
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
           $expr: { $eq: [{ $size: "$matches" }, 0] }
        }
    }
]);
```

This has been tested with the following collection template and [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) online editor :

```
db={
  "Matches": [
    { "_id": 0 },
    { "_id": 1 },
    { "_id": 2 },
    { "_id": 3 },
    { "_id": 4 },
  ],
  "Teams": [
    {
      "_id": 0,
      matches: [ 0, 3 ],
    },
    {
      "_id": 1,
      matches: [],
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      matches: [ 0 ],
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      matches: [ 2 ],
    }
  ]
}
```

The resulting output is :

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "matches": []
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "matches": []
  }
]
```